# SSRS reports Group doesn't display properly once limited rows per page

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to make a SSRS Delivery Note report which details required to be grouped by customer and use customer address as report header. One data set contains multiple customers and each customer may has 10+ lines of item details.
However detail rows are limited to 10 on each page as the delivery note paper are pre-printed.

So I group all details by customer information, use a big matrix nest with a smaller matrix to display both customer information(Header) and item detail information(Details).

In order to limit detail rows per page I use '=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/10)' command in Group.

However I notice a big side effect after doing this. For example, Customer A has 15 detail lines and Customer B has 8 Detail Lines, expected result is:

- Page 1: Customer A Address & 10 item details
- Page 2: Customer A Address & 5 item details
- Page 3: Customer B Address & 8 item details

But the actual result is:

- Page 1: Customer A Address & 10 item details
- Page 2: Customer A Address & 5 item details
- Page 3: Customer B Address & 5 item details
- Page 4: Customer B Address & 3 item details

This is because the RowNumber of customer B details are start from 16, so only 5 lines are displayed on first Customer B page, which is unexpected. Is there any possible way to achieve expected result?

[image: Pic:Big matrix nest with small matrix]

[image: Pic:limit rows per page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your second condition on the grouping:

```
=Ceiling(Rownumber(Nothing)/10)
```

This groups and thus triggers a page break on every 10th line, regardless of the customer that the lines are for. In your example, Customer C would only have 7 lines on their first page because 23 have been printed so far in total, 15 for A and 8 for B.

Hopefully your dataset is based on Sql because we can calculate the group page number within the query result using some built-in features `Row_Number`, `Over`, and `Partition`:

```
SELECT Floor((Row_Number() OVER(partition by CustomerName ORDER BY CustomerName, ItemNumber)-1) / 10) AS GroupPageNumber, 
  CustomerName, ItemNumber
FROM Items 
ORDER BY CustomerName, ItemNumber
```

This calculates the group page number with a maximum number of 10 items per page, so now you just have your second grouping expression as simply `=Fields!GroupPageNumber.Value`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solution works. However I still think the layout(like 10 rows per page) should be managed in report rather than in SQL query. Is there any possible way to make it done in SSRS configurations?

Comment: There isn't a property for maximum rows per page. You could play with the bottom margin settings to try to enforce this for the report but the problem will come in the web viewer where the interactive height is more like a guide than a rule and you may get more or less rows displayed in the browser. If preview wasn't important you could probably get it to work that way.

Comment: I tried to use page height before, however for the case 10+ rows for one customer, the detail on second page would not display group header again. And as group header data is dynamic, I can't set 'Repeat on each page' to true. I also tried to use variable rather than rowcount in report as group criteria, however SSRS could not accept variable as group criteria.. I just wonder if there is no way to do this in SSRS....

Comment: But there is a way to do it in SSRS - as you said in your first comment "this solution works". Be happy, check the working report in to source control, tick the task as done, congratulate yourself on successfully delivering this report and move on to the next thing. Don't get so caught up in things having to work the way you want them to, it is working. The user doesn't care if the heavy lifting was done by SQL or SSRS or an infinite number of monkeys on typewriters, they just want a working report and that is what they have. Smile, you delivered, life is good!

Comment: Lol you are right, life is good for both of us :). Thank you for your great help.