# How to display n number of rows between two groups in SSRS 2010

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

Using SSRS 2010
I have Two groups YearMonth and Insured. I need to display only 50 records per page based on a group "Insured". So I have created parent group "GroupPageBreakOnly" and used this expression `=CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/50)`.
I ensured that the Page Break at end is checked so that individual groups appear in individual page.
As a result the first page displays 31 rows, the second one 50 rows, and the third one 9 rows. 
[image]

I tried to specify data region "Insured"

```
=CEILING(RowNumber("Insured")/50),
```

but it gives me an error:

```
...the value of the scope parameter of RowNumber must equal  the name of the group directly containing the current group.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS reports Group doesn't display properly once limited rows per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101280/ssrs-reports-group-doesnt-display-properly-once-limited-rows-per-page)

Comment: You can't use the **Insured** in your higher-level `GroupPageBreak` grouping - it hasn't been created yet. The other way around would work - but not be helpful to you. Maybe subtract the YEARMOs if you want to exclude them? `(RowNumber(Nothing) - COUNTDISTINCT(YEARMO))...`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need this report to do other things, I would apply the grouping and aggregation in the Dataset itself which is generally a lot more efficient anyway.

Have you tried using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YearMonth, Insured ORDER BY YearMonth, Insured)` to give the number of rows, perhaps even throwing in a `% 50` at the end to see which group of 50 it fell into?

This can then be grouped on in your report.